# Get list of canonical urls?

Tags: 6, path-aliases

I have a list of ~2500 pages that I need to get canonical urls for from an old D6 site.  The site uses Path_Redirect.

Using mysql queries I can get a list of nids for the pages I want, but I'm having trouble connecting the nids to the most current path alias.  Little help?

Comment: Have you tried a sitemap module like XML sitemap https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap ?

Comment: Are you interested in the canonical URL or the path alias? The first is simply `node/$nid`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno That's actually a good question.  We are sharing our content with some partners and want to include a canonical url that points back to our site as the canonical source.  Should that url be `node/$nid` or should it be the current (and at this point, stable) path alias?

Comment: A path alias can always change, especially when the web site is multilingual, or you use the Pathauto module to generate path aliases. Drupal guarantees the node ID is unique for each node, so `http://example.com/node/$nid` will always be a valid URL that points to the same node.

Comment: Maybe I'm using 'canonical' to broadly... If we give another website some of our content and provide a link tag of `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/node/123`, is that acceptable?  Or does Google see it as a problem that the canonical url we provided will be 301 redirected to `http://www.example.com/awesome-node-title`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this problem, though I'm not sure we're using Path Redirect. For me, Migrate is bringing in URLs that are non-canonical, and I need to override the query to get the URLs that D6 has decided are canonical.

In D6 the code that does this is drupal_lookup_path('alias', $path);

By examining this I determined that if you don't care about language, the bare query is (for node/121):

```
SELECT dst FROM url_alias WHERE src = 'node/121'  ORDER BY pid DESC;
```

The ORDER BY pid DESC is the key part here.